Chrome dev tools recorded tests to be used in Selenium?
I am using Google Chrome Dev Tools Recorder to create tests and export them as JSON or Cypress tests. This is working great, but now we have a need to implement these tests into Selenium IDE. Is it possible to be done and can the already created JSON tests be used in Selenium?

It is possible to build a custom Recorder extension to export to the format you need https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/recorder/extensions#build-extension All published extensions can be found here https://chromewebstore.google.com/collection/customize_recorder?pli=1
